# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot redefine property: origin' in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, dom, jasmine

I have scenario where

```
if(window.location.origin){
    //list of operations
}else{
    //list of operations
}
```

I am trying to assign value to [window.location.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties) which is `readonly` property for unit testing purpose in Jasmine using

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'origin', {
   value: '',
   writable: true,
}
```

but I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: origin`

I have tried following solutions which is for `jest` which suggest to change in `jsdom` and use `reconfigure` to change value of testing environment. Is there way to do this in jasmine? I am able to get `Env() using jasmine.getEnv()` for jasmine but not able to set it.

[Unable to change window.location using Object.defineProperty](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124)

[Unable to redefine properties of the window object](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6886)

Comment: Changing the _origin_ is usually forbidden, even using _Object.defineProperty_. What you could do instead is define a method like:
        `function getOrigin() {
        return window.location.origin;
        }
`
And use this method in your code. In the test, you can stub the method _getOrigin_ to return what you want.

Comment: Thanks @mgarcia that did the trick

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this for the sake of tests only in NodeJS, try redefine its constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location.constructor.prototype, 'origin', {
   value: '',
   configurable: true,
});
```

Note, that within browsers this will not throw an error, but also will not do anything.